# Delay in launching activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am launching one `Intent` over another.
And it is expected that background `Activity` should no be shown to user.
But it seems there is delay while launching 2nd `Activity`.
Due to this for some seconds first `Activity` is visible to user.
How can i avoid this?

I am starting new activity simply using an intent and `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: Are you in some way or another blocking the main thread in 2nd Activity? Posting onCreate and onResume part of the code from your 2nd Activity would help.

Comment: Can you just clarify somethings, first what do you mean by background activity, second what do you mean by "Due to this for some seconds first activity is visible to user" i think i got it but i want to be sure.